# java.net.UnknownHostException always happened in kubernetes with aws direct connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, kubernetes, coredns

I deployed a kubernetes cluster (v1.11) in a hybrid environment connected by aws direct connect service. There are 3 ec2 nodes in one vpc and another bare metal server.

Every thing works will except the bad network. I have some java web services running in kubernetes and I set `nodeSelector` to make all of them running in ec2. And there had shown a lot of `java.net.UnknownHostException` when the service trying to access some services through http. It did not happen every time but it is quite frequent.

I tried some method to check the problem. For example, I checked the coredns service, and found out a lot of timeout over there. I solved the timeout problem by following [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/193) but the `java.net.UnknownHostException` is still shown.

I also found [this link](https://aws.amazon.com/cn/blogs/opensource/unified-service-discovery-ecs-kubernetes/) but I am not sure if this is related with my problem.

Hope someone can solve my problem. I do suffer a lot of this. Thanks in advance.

And recently I found some one has similar problem with me, it may related with the `coredns` in kubernetes.

Comment: Interesting infra architecture! Curious about the latency between k8s nodes on-prem and on AWS: if your services/pods are restarted/recycled I wouldn't be surprised you ultimately blame the latency for k8s intra dns to synchronize between nodes.

Comment: Can you get a more verbose error to pinpoint from which k8s node the failing requests come from and which nodes are they supposedly headed to? Might help confirming latency or simply a network issue.

Comment: @Clorichel So you said the connect latency is the main reason? And the aws direct connect with 1Gb band is not good enough? And the error node is the one in aws. And the error is shown because it resolve dns failed. The only communication between the nodes are coredns request and response which shows no error.

Comment: "I wouldn't be surprised" if it was, can't guess the reason :) So suggesting you to clarify the error by gathering and providing more details: obviously looks like dns resolution, but from where to where? Between AWS nodes only or not? Can you reproduce and how? Can you share some logs? That will help anyone help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch cni plugin from flannel to calico solved this problem.